# Bundle install: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/bundle: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had uninstalled my previous ruby version 1.9.1 and installed ruby through RVM as per this video.

Which ruby: /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby

which bundle: /home/vishnu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/bin/bundle

After creating rails new app, I had to run sudo bundle install
Iam getting the error
Error: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/bundle: No such file or directory.

Comment: Video url: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hiPQynmnsiI

Comment: Try running which bundler to find out the path of from where your bundler is launched

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` runs in a different environment. Use `rvmsudo` if you want your RVM settings to propagate.